# Difference between TeXstudio on Windows and latex on Linux

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I have the following source file:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section without standard heading}
    Doc goes here.  
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with TeXstudio on Windows then the resultant pdf has the bookmark. But, when I compile it on Linux with

```bash
latex book.tex; dvipdfm book;
```

it doesn't have any bookmarks.
[image]
How can fix it for the Linux environment?

I have the same problem with hyperlinks, they are clickable on TeXstudio/Windows and not clickable in the Linux environment.

```bash
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compile directly with pdflatex.

```
pdflatex book.tex
```

Alternative you can view the used commands in texstudio under settings.

Background: The Information about the document structure is lost when compiling to dvi first and then to pdf.